# Laravel Queue is Processed but email not found in inbox

Tags: laravel

I Am sending emails in Laravel Queue. While using the send method, as shown here

```
Mail::to($userSocial->getEmail())->send(new WelcomeEmail('1234567', "haha", "Makamu"));
```

my email is delivered to my inbox. However when i switch to queue like below

```
Mail::to($userSocial->getEmail())->queue(new WelcomeEmail('1234567', "haha", "Makamu"));
```

I also used this method

```
SendEmailSocialReg::dispatch('12345678', "haha", "Makamu");
```

and monitor via `queue:listen` i am get the processing. then processed message. No error however.

What could be wrong?

my WelcomeEmail

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class WelcomeEmail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $password;
public $client_name;
public $client_email;
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($password, $email, $name)
{
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->client_name = $name;
    $this->client_email = $email;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email.auto');
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the "WelcomeEmail" codes?

Comment: Added the WelcomeEmail

Comment: Here does'nt seen a problem. Could you started the queue worker with "artisan queue:work --queue=default"?

Comment: `evans@evans-HP-Pavilion-x360-m3-Convertible:/var/www/html/mkulimayoung$ php artisan queue:work --tries=2 --queue=default`                                                                                                   which produces:
`[2018-09-22 16:36:01][864] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail`
`[2018-09-22 16:36:13][864] Processed:  App\Mail\WelcomeEmail` but no email received

Comment: Okey it seeing successfully executed?

Comment: Yes it processes, but i dont receive any mail

Comment: The configs are correct because if i send an email directly, `Mail::to($userSocial->getEmail())->send(new WelcomeEmail('1234567', "haha", "Makamu"));` i get it in my inbox. However, if i use queue, i don't get it

Comment: Could you change your build() function in the WelcomeEmail with my answer?

Comment: Yea, i've tried with the markdown, but still same outcome.

Comment: Sorry, Then I don't knew why didn't sent e-mail. Because I said each of the possibilities which I realized...

Comment: Ok. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Your WelcomeEmail class must return markdown() at build() function like this:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('email.auto');
}
```

Then the queue worker must be executed with this command:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=default
```

Comment: `evans@evans-HP-Pavilion-x360-m3-Convertible:/var/www/html/mkulimayoung$ php artisan queue:work --tries=2 --queue=default` which produces:
`[2018-09-22 16:36:01][864] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail`
`[2018-09-22 16:36:13][864] Processed:  App\Mail\WelcomeEmail` but i dont get any email

Comment: It's about of your mail configurations which are in the .env file beginning with MAIL_ prefix.